# Finite generatation of Ext

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, injective-modules

If $A$ is a Noetherian ring and $M$, $N$ are finitely generated modules over $A$, it is easy to see that $\mbox{Ext}_{A}(M,N)$ is finitely generated by taking a finitely generated projective resolution of $M$. But if I take an injective resolution of $N$ instead, it is not at all clear to me why $\mbox{Ext} _{A}(M,N)$ should be finitely generated. It is my understanding that injective hulls are in general not finitely generated. Does this mean that if I take $\mbox{Hom}(M,-)$ of the injective resolution and compute its cohomology I magically get a finitely generated module?

Comment: Yes. It does mean that.

Comment: You'll get the $\mathrm{Ext}_A^k(M,N)$ which will be finitely
generated; whether that is magical or not isn't really
a mathematical question.

Comment: Getting a finitely generated module from a possibly monstrously huge module is a bit hard for me to swallow. I was hoping there might be some straight forward explanation without translating it to the projective world.

Comment: You get finitely generated abelian groups from taking the homology
of the singular chain complex of a CW-complex with finitely
many cells. This chain complex is likely to be even more
monstrously huge :-)

Comment: Heck, a slight variant of the same example, if you have a projective variety $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and a coherent sheaf $F$ on $X$, then the cohomology $H^i(X, F)$ are finitely dimensional vector spaces!  They are also computed using an injective resolution of $F$.  

Comment: I think the question has a lot of potential. As Robin and Karl pointed out, there are a lot of examples of complexes of "big" objects with "small" cohomology. It would be nice if someone can give some underlying reasons. 